# Run two System.threading.timers in a single windows service

Tags: vb.net, timer

I need two separate `System.threading.timer` instances to be running and I have set up my service to run this way however the second timer is not firing off ever. The first continues to fire properly. This I show I call the two timers:

```
Dim timerDelegate As TimerCallback = AddressOf tick
Dim autoEvent As New AutoResetEvent(True)
Dim milliseconds As Integer = My.Settings.second * 1000 + 60 * 1000 *       My.Settings.minute + 60 * 60 * 1000 * My.Settings.hour        
Dim dt As New System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 0, milliseconds)

Dim timerDelegate2 As TimerCallback = AddressOf tick2              
Dim autoEvent2 As New AutoResetEvent(True)    
Dim milliseconds2 As Integer = 10 * 1000 * My.Settings.time    
Dim dt2 As New System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 0, milliseconds)
```

and this is the code for the first timer

```
Private Sub tick(ByVal stateInfo As Object) ' to delete the clt files    
   log.message("inside this one")   
   Dim files As String()   
   files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcefile, "*")   
   Dim file As String   
   Dim r2 As Regex = New Regex(".*\.clt|.*\.CLT")   
   For Each file In files   
       Dim mathcer2 As Match = r2.Match(file) 'match for clt   
       If mathcer2.Success Then    
           System.IO.File.Delete(file)   

       End If   
    Next   
End Sub
```

The second  timer has much the same code.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is?
Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same delegate instance for both timers:

```
Dim dt2 As New System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 0, milliseconds
```

should be:

```
Dim dt2 As New System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate2, autoEvent, 0, milliseconds
```

You are also using the same `AutoResetEvent` object for both also.  Unclear to me what you are doing but it seems you've copied/pasted too much.

Comment: damn thats fast thanks for your quick response, this place is fantastic